# What are the long-term consequences of using <cfdocument> without a filename attribute, so that it outputs a PDF within the browser?

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, windows-server-2012, coldfusion-11

Long story short:

A few years ago when I was learning ColdFusion (around the time of CF 8), a colleague told me to be careful when generating temporary files. Apparently there is or was a bug where ColdFusion hung onto temp files and the temp folder could grow to be many GB in size, eventually crashing the application, if not cleared out routinely.

---

Whether that was correct or not, it stuck with me.

Now, I'm presented with a project where to save on storage space, it would be awesome to generate PDFs only as needed. I'm using CF11 on Windows Server 2012.

Can anyone tell me what, if anything, I need to look out for? Anything I could do to mitigate the risk of server error or streamlining the process? I just want to be sure I'm not writing something that'll be a game-breaker if it's ever used at a high volume.

For reference, the code is something like this:

```
<cfdocument 
    format = "PDF"  
    marginBottom = "0.5" 
    marginLeft = "0.5" 
    marginRight = "0.5" 
    marginTop = "0.3" 
    orientation = "portrait" 
    pageHeight = "11" 
    pageWidth = "8.5" 
    unit = "in">
```

Pretty bare. I'm just curious about how the server will react long-term.

Comment: Why not test it out?  Generate a few dozen PDFs to see what impact they have on your server.

Comment: @EatPeanutButter I have. I don't see any space being eaten up and the speed/performance is fine.  But I will never be able to simulate the kind of use a mid-sized business might put it through. There are companies who do nothing except safety inspections via an online form, generate the PDFs, and download them for record keeping. 15,000 a month. I'm wondering what I can expect with that kind of volume. Or if CF has a weakness.

Comment: Have you considered writing the PDF data to a blob field in a database? Then you effectively have a cached (fast!) version and you don't use space on your web server.

Comment: You say, `if not cleared out routinely.`.  Pick certain directories and clear them out routinely.

Comment: @DanBracuk Could you offer a little guidance on where CF stores temporary documents created with `<cfdocument>` by default, or how to alter that? A little elucidation would be great.